# MySQL Inserts with condition

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I am wondering if there is a way to restrict MySQL INSERTs on a given condition, for example:

We have a table with projects and another table with employees. The maximum allowed people in a project is restricted to 5. How can we do this in MySQL?

Thanks in advance,
Marley

Answer (score 1):

You have to read about [constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp), [check](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp) (or value based) type.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   ...
   numPeople INT CHECK (numPeople <= 5)
   ...
)
```

---

*Yeah, sorry, check constraint doesn't work in MySQL*

Answer (score 1):

You can't enforce this constraint via the schema without breaking the relation (i.e. having 5 `employees` columns).  MySQL does not allow `CHECK` constraints.

You can `SELECT` the number of employees separately before doing the query, *or* you can use `INSERT ... SELECT` with the restriction.

```
INSERT INTO Employees
    (employee, column, names)
SELECT
    ?, ?, ?
FROM
    Projects
    NATURAL JOIN Employees
WHERE
    projID = ?
GROUP BY
    projID
HAVING
    COUNT(empID) < 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly use a trigger to check the number of users prior to insert:-

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER project_before_insert_allow_only_five_employees
     BEFORE INSERT ON project FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
          IF (SELECT COUNT(employee_id) FROM project WHERE project_id=NEW.project_id) > 4
          THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: only 5 employees on a project';
          END IF;
     END;
```

Not tested, and assuming that your project table has a row per employee (easy enough to modify if the project id is instead stored on the employees table for those associated with it).